# Can not see anything on Live View screen

Tags: astrophotography

I am using a Nikon D3300 camera with Liveview on my 8SE telescope. Using a 25x eyepiece to look at planets. Can not seem to find anything in the liveview. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Can you see anything in the liveview when you look at something else? Do you see anything in images if you've taken them?

Comment: Welcome to that wonderful low noise sensor in the D3300. It interprets the stars as noise and eliminates them.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you see anything in the liveview when you look at something else? Do you see anything in images if you've taken them? - mattdm

This is important. If you see on normal daylight conditions, it is simply that live view has a maximum framerate.

It is arround 1/30 because it is a video feedback. If your exposure is too dark, for example to take a picture you need 10 seconds, the live view simply won't display it.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I was not aware of that! I appreciate your help.

Comment: I went out this evening again with the telescope and camera.  I still can not see anything with the prime setup.So I switched to a 25mm lens with no camera and found my Mars target. Quickly put the camera back on with an extention tube and again could not find anything. All in manual of course.  Just can't figure out what I am not doing correctly.....

Comment: Turns out the the star pointer ( cheap version) was the culprit.  One of the screws was loose and throwing the scope into a different area entirely. I did, finally, get to video Mars.  I so much appreciate all of the help.  Thank you-Dave